# Linking in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I have a Rails API and EmberCLI frontend app. My page shows a list of artists. Click on artist should send user on page with all albums of the artist. I need to make a link to user's albums page. Each artist has his own page with albums. Like localhost:4200/artists/1. Here's what I have:

My router:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

const Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('artists');
  this.route('artist', { path: 'artist/:artist_id' });
});


export default Router;
```

model Artist:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  itunes_id: DS.attr('number'),
  albums: DS.hasMany('album')

});
```

model Album:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  artwork_url_100: DS.attr('string'),
  artist_id: DS.attr('number'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('artist')

});
```

Routes: 1)artist.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('artist')
    return this.store.findRecord('artist', params.artist_id);}
    });
```

2) album.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
  return this.store.findAll('album');}
});
```

Comment: I need to make a link to user's albums page. Each artist has his own page with albums.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for [linking](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/links/)

Answer (score 2):

Like @timmy-omahony mentioned, there's a [whole guide about linking](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/templates/links/) in the documentation. You need to use the `link-to` helper, and pass it the appropriate configurations:

```
{{#link-to 'artist' 1}}Artist page{{/link-to}}
```

In this example I used what is called the block form of the `link-to` helper. The content between the handlebars tag will be the content inside the link anchor. I'm telling it to link to the `artist` page for the artist with id `1`.

You can also pass the value dynamically:

```
{{#link-to 'artist' artist.id}}Artist page{{/link-to}}
```

Or you can pass the artist object itself, the model hook will be skipped, and by default the id will be serialized to the URL:

```
{{#link-to 'artist' artist.id}}Artist page{{/link-to}}
```